# NoMethodError: undefined method ' ' for main:Object - whenever scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake, whenever

I can't get **reminder.rake** to work in production. I get an error.

```
namespace :challenges do
  desc 'Send email to users with challenges who want reminder'
  task challenge_reminder: :environment do
    self.all.each do |challenge|
      UserMailer.challenge_reminder(self).deliver_now # Tried (challenge) instead of (self), same error too
    end 
  end
end
```

**heroku scheduler**

[image]

**trace error**

```
Anthony-Gallis-MacBook-Pro:livetochallenge galli01anthony$ heroku run rake challenges:challenge_reminder --trace
Running rake challenges:challenge_reminder --trace on livetochallenge... up, run.7666
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for main:Object
/app/lib/tasks/reminder.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => challenges:challenge_reminder
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Anthony-Gallis-MacBook-Pro:livetochallenge galli01anthony$
```

As an **example** I have below working so I know it isn't a problem with setting up the **[whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)** or heroku scheduler:

```
namespace :challenges do
  desc 'Clean the challenge freebies and freebie_dates'
  task clean: :environment do
    Challenge.update_all(freebie: 0, freebie_date: nil)
  end
end
```

Comment: Which line is it of the lines you pasted here?

Comment: That's not source. What is line 4 of that file? Is that the snippet at the end?

Comment: You still haven't clarified what line 4 of that file contains. There's a reference to `rake` in there that shouldn't be present.

Comment: That's weird I guess they are some how interconnected. One error in one file has an effect on another? I'll remove that file and updated question @tadman

Comment: What is `self` in `self.all.each`? That line makes no sense to me. You probably need to specify a specific model class. The `(self)` part should be `(challenge)` or you're iterating over records and not even using them.

Comment: Okay I removed `self.all.each do |challenge|` as a test and now the error is `NoMethodError: undefined method 'user_id' for main:Object`. Now I try and  see by putting it back and changing `(self)` to `(challenge)` @tadman

Comment: Should I make `self.all.each do |challenge|` into `Challenge.all.each` @tadman? I originally had the method in the challenge.rb model but I moved it directly into the rake file

Comment: Yes, when you move the code, the context/scope changes. So you have to change `self.all.each do |challenge|` to `Challenge.all.each do |challenge|`

Comment: Thanks @tadman for your patience. Mission Accomplished :)

Comment: Thanks @Dharam you rock and roll! Btw would you still be willing to help me over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994797/how-to-update-two-form-from-one-submit/35995311?noredirect=1#comment59645581_35995311? I had updated the question for you

Comment: Remember `self` in Ruby is highly context sensitive, and inside a `rake` file it's not the model any longer.

Comment: Yea that makes a lot of sense. I kept moving that code around I didn't think to change that. Now I have a better sense of how to test rake @tadman, the man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem here with your Rake task:

```
task challenge_reminder: :environment do
  self.all.each do |challenge|
    UserMailer.challenge_reminder(self).deliver_now
  end 
end
```

Here `self` refers to the Rake task context, not the model where this code originated. You'll also need to do something with `challenge` or there's no point in retrieving it.

Suggested fix:

```
task challenge_reminder: :environment do
  Challenge.all.each do |challenge|
    UserMailer.challenge_reminder(challenge).deliver_now
  end
end
```

Remember that calling `.all` on a model with a lot of records may use enormous amounts of memory and could crash your server if it gets too huge because Rails will load every single record into memory. If you have millions of those, you're probably toast.

When trying to trace back to problems, look at the line referenced in the error first and work back from there. Ruby's stack trace is usually specific enough to get to the root of the problem.

Comment: depending on Rails version a suggestion of `in_batches` or `find_in_batches`  or `find_each` if you don't care about the default batch size of 1000 to handle those large data sets you are talking about might be worth while.

Answer (score 1):

According to the trace, looks like line 4 of the file `/app/lib/tasks/clear_deadline.rake` is referring to `rake`, which is why it is failing.

Review the contents of the file, or provide the code of that file.

Comment: Thank you for narrowing down the issue. I updated the question to get to the root of the problem with that file. But I give you many plus as thanks :]